# Error in CRC32 computation in MSbit first mode

Tags: c, crc

Until now I have been computing a CRC32 with the STM32H7 hardware CRC.

The setup is:

- polynom `0x04C11DB7`
- RefIn and RefOut = false (no bit order inversion)
- init value 0xFFFFFFFF
- no Xor of the CRC at the end

Obviously the results of this HW CRC setup have been verified against two online CRC calculators.

For some reasons I'm trying to get the same result with a pure software implementation.

I could get a working "LSbit first" version of the software (of course the computed CRC is different than the HW one, but I verified it with two online CRC calculators).

However I could not get a working MSbit first version (that should give the same result as the HW CRC32).

The code is the following for MSbit first (it's just quick and dirty evaluation code that I picked up from the web):

```
static unsigned long crc_table_msb[256] = {
0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b,
(...)
0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c, 0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf, 0xa2f33668,
0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4};

unsigned long update_crc_msb(unsigned long crc,
              unsigned char *buf, int len)
{
    unsigned long c = crc ^ 0xffffffffL;
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < len; n++) 
    {
        c = crc_table_msb[(((c >> 24)&0xFF) ^ buf[n]) & 0xff] ^ (c << 8);
    }
    return c;// ^ 0xffffffffL;
}


unsigned long crc_msb(unsigned char *buf, int len)
{
    return update_crc_msb(0L, buf, len);
}
```

With the usual check input (0x31, 0x32, ..., 0x39) I get:

- with HW CRC: `0x0376e6e7`  (correct, see below from crccalc.com)
- with SW LSbit first: `0x340bc6d9` (correct, bit order inverted)
- with SW MSbit first: `0x369b34b1`

Do you see something wrong in the C code ?

PS: Reference results
[image]

Comment: Aside: should `0xffffffffL` be `0xffffffffUL` or perhaps `ULONG_MAX`? What size is `unsigned long` on your system?

Comment: @WeatherVane of course you're right, as I said, quick'n'dirty copy paste. Doesn't change anything though. Unsigned long is 32 bits

Comment: Did you try trivial data, like a single bit set on different positions? This might give a hint on the error.

Comment: `unsigned long` is 64 bits on my test machine, but I get the correct answer if I change your `return c;` to `return c & 0xfffffffful;` to truncate the returned value to 32 bits.

Comment: You can't give an example from your actual hardware CRC? Why should you trust online CRC calculators or your use of them?

Comment: Well the online calculator gives the same result as STM32 HW CRC. It always gave the right results every time I used it (talking about crccalc.com)

Comment: @IanAbbott this is interesting. So you get 0x0376e6e7  ?

Comment: @MarkAdler there is an example of hardware CRC, it is equal to the check value of MPEG CRC (as you noticed)

Comment: Yes, `printf("%lx\n", crc_msb("123456789", 9));` prints `376e6e7` for me.

Comment: I assume you are calculating the CRC from a single chunk of data, because XOR'ing the CRC with 0xffffffff for every chunk would make no sense. In fact it would be better to remove the initial XOR from the update function and take care of it externally, or use a parameter to indicate first section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is the MPEG-2 CRC:

```
width=32 poly=0x04c11db7 init=0xffffffff refin=false refout=false xorout=0x00000000 check=0x0376e6e7 residue=0x00000000 name="CRC-32/MPEG-2"
```

I have no idea if that actually matches your hardware CRC or not, but this implements it:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint32_t const table_byte[] = {
    0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b,
    0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005, 0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6, 0x2b4bcb61,
    0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd, 0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7,
    0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9, 0x5f15adac, 0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75,
    0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f, 0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011, 0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3,
    0x709f7b7a, 0x745e66cd, 0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039,
    0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5, 0xbe2b5b58, 0xbaea46ef,
    0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81, 0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033, 0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d,
    0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe, 0xd9714b49, 0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb,
    0xceb42022, 0xca753d95, 0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1,
    0xe13ef6f4, 0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d, 0x34867077, 0x30476dc0,
    0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae, 0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5, 0x2ac12072,
    0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16, 0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4,
    0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca, 0x7897ab07, 0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde,
    0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c, 0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02, 0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08,
    0x571d7dd1, 0x53dc6066, 0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
    0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e, 0xbfa1b04b, 0xbb60adfc,
    0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692, 0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698, 0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6,
    0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d, 0x94ea7b2a, 0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050,
    0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e, 0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2,
    0xc6bcf05f, 0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686, 0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34,
    0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a, 0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80, 0x644fc637,
    0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb, 0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1,
    0x46863638, 0x42472b8f, 0x5c007b8a, 0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53,
    0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629, 0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47, 0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5,
    0x3f9b762c, 0x3b5a6b9b, 0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff,
    0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623, 0xf12f560e, 0xf5ee4bb9,
    0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7, 0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65, 0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b,
    0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8, 0xda649d6f, 0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd,
    0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3, 0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7,
    0xae3afba2, 0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b, 0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71,
    0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f, 0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74, 0x857130c3,
    0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640, 0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2,
    0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c, 0x7b827d21, 0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8,
    0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a, 0x61043093, 0x65c52d24, 0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e,
    0x18197087, 0x1cd86d30, 0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
    0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088, 0x2497d08d, 0x2056cd3a,
    0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654, 0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce, 0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0,
    0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb, 0xdbee767c, 0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676,
    0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18, 0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4,
    0x89b8fd09, 0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0, 0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662,
    0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c, 0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf, 0xa2f33668,
    0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4
};

uint32_t crc32mpeg_2_byte(uint32_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffffffff;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc = (crc << 8) ^
              table_byte[((crc >> 24) ^ data[i]) & 0xff];
    }
    return crc;
}
```

You need to not exclusive-or the CRC initially with `0xffffffff`. Instead your call needs to be: `return update_crc_msb(0xffffffff, buf, len);`

I should note that the convention here is that you call the CRC routine with a data pointer of `NULL` in order to get the initial value to provide in a chain of CRC calculations. So it would be used thusly:

```
uint32_t crc = crc32mpeg_2_byte(0, NULL, 0);
crc = crc32mpeg_2_byte(crc, chunk_1, len_1);
crc = crc32mpeg_2_byte(crc, chunk_2, len_2);
...
crc = crc32mpeg_2_byte(crc, chunk_n, len_n);
```

Comment: Isn't it exactly the same as my code ? (I confirm the table is identical)

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Yours has a harmless extra `& 0xFF` but it is otherwise equivalent for the case where your update function is called only once per data stream (assuming `unsigned long` is 32 bits on your system).

Comment: @IanAbbott that's what I understood too

Comment: So I confirm I get the correct value with Mark 's code. I still don't understand the difference with my own code (that I'd picked up on the web) but it's not linked to CRC algorithmic issues, more to C or gcc subtleties

Comment: There are two key differences. First off, your "update" is not an update, since you messed up the initial value. Second, the code in my answer is using `uint32_t`, which assures that there are not any extraneous bits in the high 32 bits of a possibly 64-bit `unsigned long`. The latter is easily remedied however with an `& 0xffffffff` at the end. You're only showing eight hex digits of results, so you're effectively doing that anyway. How exactly you're getting an error cannot be seen, since you do not show how you use your code. Specifically what your initial value of `crc` is.

Comment: By the way, the problem with your code is indeeed a CRC algorithmic issue, since you are not handing the initial value correctly.